# Test case neither passes nor fails in VS

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

In VS Express 2013, I run the following program against certain test cases written in a spec file. The code and a portion of the spec file is as follows:

```
struct DOB {
    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int stringToValue(char* temp) {
    int num = 0;
    while (*temp != '-' && *temp != '\0') {
        if (((*temp) >= '0') && ((*temp) <= '9')) {
            num = num * 10 + ((*temp) - '0');
            ++temp;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int isValidFormat(char* dob) {
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; dob[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (!((dob[i] >= '0' && dob[i] <= '9' || dob[i] == '-')))
            return 0;
        ++length;
    }
    return length;
}

int function(int value1, int value2) {
    if (value1>value2) {
        return 2;
    }

    else if (value1<value2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int isLeap(int year) {
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100)) {
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        if (year % 400 == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int isValid(struct DOB d) {
    if (d.year>0) {
        if (d.month>0 && d.month <= 12) {
            if (d.month == 2 && isLeap(d.year) == 1) {
                if (d.date>0 && d.date <= 29) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (d.date > 0 && d.date <= 28) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else if (d.date == 1 || d.date == 3 || d.date == 5 || d.date == 7 || d.date == 8 || d.date == 10 || d.date == 12){
                if (d.date > 0 && d.date <= 31) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else {
                if (d.date > 0 && d.date <= 30) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isOlder(char* dob1, char* dob2) {
    struct DOB d1, d2;

    if (isValidFormat(dob1)!= 10 && isValidFormat(dob2) != 10)
        return -1;

    d1.date = stringToValue(dob1);
    d2.date = stringToValue(dob2);
    d1.month = stringToValue(dob1 + 3);
    d2.month = stringToValue(dob2 + 3);
    d1.year = stringToValue(dob1 + 6);
    d2.year = stringToValue(dob2 + 6);

    if (isValid(d1) == 1 && isValid(d2) == 1) {
        if (function(d1.year, d2.year) != 0)
            return function(d1.year, d2.year);
        else if (function(d1.month, d2.month) != 0)
            return function(d1.month, d2.month);
        else
            return function(d1.date, d2.date);
    }

    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

---

In the spec file containing test cases:

```
TEST_METHOD(isOlderinvalid)
                {
                    Assert::AreEqual(-1, isOlder("1000", "15-07-2000"), L"isOlder: invalid input case failed", LINE_INFO());
                    Assert::AreEqual(-1, isOlder("15-07-2000", "000"), L"isOlder: invalid input case failed", LINE_INFO());
                    Assert::AreEqual(-1, isOlder("15-0A-2000", "15-07-2000"), L"isOlder: invalid input case failed", LINE_INFO());
                    Assert::AreEqual(-1, isOlder("15-13-2000", "15-07-2000"), L"isOlder: invalid input case failed", LINE_INFO());
                    Assert::AreEqual(-1, isOlder("29-02-2001", "15-07-2000"), L"isOlder: invalid input case failed", LINE_INFO());
                }
```

When I run the following test cases on my local compiler, I get the expected output. But when I run the tests on the above code, I neither pass nor fail the above test cases. I'm honestly not sure what's wrong. It seems like a VS-specific problem rather than a problem with my code.

Comment: Did you tried to do some debugging on VS to know which part of the code didn't branched as you expected?

Comment: `isValidFormat("0000000000")` and `isValidFormat("----------")` both return non-zero.  Not much of a format check.

Comment: `stringToValue()` is an infinite loop should it get called with non-digit, non-`-` characters.  Suggest making function `static` as it is only useful with controlled use.

Comment: `Assert::AreEqual` --> invalid C code.  Are you using a C compiler?

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is clearly not C code.

Comment: @chux My code is written in c. The Assert::AreEqual is in the spec file containing test cases written by someone else. I check if the date contains a non-digit, non-`-` character before calling stringToValue(), but the error condition was wrong. I'll try to write a better function for format checking, though. My local compiler returned -1 for the cases above (as expected) because it failed the latter isValid check. But in VS, it was entering an infinite loop with stringToValue(). I've solved the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong error condition

```
// if (isValidFormat(dob1)!= 10 && isValidFormat(dob2) != 10)
if (isValidFormat(dob1)!= 10 || isValidFormat(dob2) != 10)
    return -1;
```

When only 1 format was invalid, code called weak function `stringToValue()` which has an infinite loop with invalid input.

```
int stringToValue(char* temp) {
    int num = 0;
    while (*temp != '-' && *temp != '\0') {
        if (((*temp) >= '0') && ((*temp) <= '9')) {
            num = num * 10 + ((*temp) - '0');
            ++temp;  //  Move this to outside `if()` test
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Perhaps additional problems.

Unclear how code "worked" on OP's local compiler.  Maybe `Assert()` was not active.

Comment: Thanks! This, and a few other minor problems, was causing it. Is there a better way to format check, though, that you'd suggest? Would love to know what you think!